# Only Last random number insert in database not all

Tags: php, cakephp

i have made a code to generate 11 digit random number and i want to save all number in database

admin_create_epin.ctp(view)

```
<tr>
   Add E-pin:(No of E-Pin)
   <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('e_pin',array('label'=>false));?></td> 
</tr>
```

epins_controlller.php

```
 public function admin_create_epin(){

   $limit = $this->data['Epin']['e_pin'];

   for($i=0;$i<$limit;$i++)
      {
         $random = substr(number_format(time() * rand(),0,'',''),0,11)."<br/>";
         $this->data['Epin']['e_pin'] = $random;

        //pr($this->data); it's show all random number

         $this->Epin->save($this->data);          // i have problem only here it's save only last random number
         $this->Session->setFlash("Epin has been added");
         $this->Redirect(array('action'=>'admin_create_epin')); 
    }   
}
```

Issue:Code generate all random number but i have problem in my code insert only last random number not all and i want to insert all random number

thanks

Comment: Not to be picky, but I would not trust your number generation. If you need a good random distribution, please use a proven random generator and don't invent your own strange operations. Here's a better random approach: `str_pad((string) mt_rand(0, 99999999999), 11, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You have to move `Redirect()` outsite the loop.

2) After the first `$this->Epin->save(...)` last inserted id is stored in `$this->Epin->id` and then is used for update records with this id for following iterations. So you will have only one record inserted, and rewritten in the last iteration.

Reset it before saving:

```
for($i=0;$i<$limit;$i++)
  {
     //...
     $this->Epin->id = null; // <- force insert in the next save
     $this->Epin->save($this->data);          // i have problem only here it's save only last random number
     //...
}
```

Also you can try `create()` method:

```
$this->Epin->save($this->Epin->create($this->data));
```

Comment: after add that line , $this->Epin->id = null; code is working

Answer (score 1):

move following lines outside the loop

```
 $this->Session->setFlash("Epin has been added");
 $this->Redirect(array('action'=>'admin_create_epin'));
```

it will work

Comment: thanks for reply, after do it url never open, that's not solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function admin_create_epin(){

   $limit = $this->data['Epin']['e_pin'];
   $this->data['Epin']['e_pin'] = array(); // assign this to be an array first.

   for($i=0;$i<$limit;$i++)
      {
         $random = substr(number_format(time() * rand(),0,'',''),0,11)."<br/>";
         $this->data['Epin']['e_pin'][] = $random; // this pushes the value onto the end of the array 'e_pin'

        //pr($this->data); it's show all random number

         $this->Epin->save($this->data);          // i have problem only here it's save only last random number
    }   

         $this->Session->setFlash("Epin has been added");
         $this->Redirect(array('action'=>'admin_create_epin')); 

}
```

Access all your numbers through `$this->data['Epin']['e_pin']` as an array. And don't redirect from a loop.

Comment: thanks for reply , i m getting tht error after use your code        [] operator not supported for strings

Comment: see my edit, you need to cast the variable as an array first.

Comment: getting that error ->preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given

Answer (score 0):

change line :  `$this->data['Epin']['e_pin'][$i] = $random;` instead of `$this->data['Epin']['e_pin'] = $random;`

and also move following lines outside the loop

```
$this->Session->setFlash("Epin has been added");
 $this->Redirect(array('action'=>'admin_create_epin'));
```